# Asp Net Core Post Request with Content-Length mismatch

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, http-headers

When testing an api using postman and adding an arbitrary **Content-Length** header that is larger than the request body size the Request will hang.

Presumably it's waiting for the rest of the body to be transferred - once the request is killed in postman Asp logs:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Unexpected end of request content

This appears to be a potential attack vector as attackers could create many of these requests.

Is there a well known pattern for getting around this problem?